# how to generate expansion panel dynamically based on number of returning objects in angular?

Tags: angular

please help me in dynamically showing data on expansion panel of angular material based on objects returned on web API.

```
    <mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      This is the expansion title
    </mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description>
      This is a summary of the content
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
    <p>This is the primary content of the panel</p>
  </ng-template>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: I want to iterate over expansion panel using *ngFor

Comment: [Help yourself](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor)

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `*ngFor` directive in the block you want to iterate:

```
<mat-accordion>
 <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of items;">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        This is the expansion title
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        This is a summary of the content
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
      <p>This is the primary content of the panel</p>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Comment: @mmodalities What's happening? Can you give me a clue?